# PostgreSQL explicit not-null violation check happens before the check constraint?

Tags: python, postgresql, logging, psycopg2

I'm trying to use named constraints to be able to tell what and where exactly happened from the error messages. For example, when I set a not-null constraint on a column "foo" in a table "bar" and then try to add a row with a null value in it I get:

```
ERROR: null value in column "foo" violates not-null constraint
```

I don't get the name of the table, and I can't use this error message to extract any useful information. On the other hand, when I remove the not-null constraint and add a `check (foo is not null)` constraint, which can be named to something like `bar__foo__nn`, I immediately get the table name, the column name, and something like an error code "nn" for not-null violation. I can even parse this constraint name to extract the needed information for further error logging in my application.

From what I've read, the explicit not-null constraint should be more efficient and allow more optimizations. Also, primary keys must have the explicit not-null constraint set. So I tried using both, but what happens is, that I only get the "default" not-null violation error above and no mention of my "custom" named constraint violation.

**Is there any way to use the explicit not-null constraint and still have some convenient way to "customize" the potential not-null violation error?**

### EDIT

I didn't mention, that I access the database with Python using psycopg2. I didn't want to make this psycopg2 specific as I use postgresql in other environments as well and a general overview of how this works in postgresql would be useful. For example, how to extract the needed information (the table name and the column name) inside a stored procedure/function to serialize it in some way inside the postgresql code (in the exception clause), so that the application connecting to the database (be it Python with psycopg2 or anything else) sees the errors the way I want them to be when calling the stored procedures.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158499/postgres-how-is-set-not-null-more-efficient-than-check-constraint

Comment: The docs say that it's more efficient, however the SE answer shows, that it's a minor difference. I am more concerned however with the fact, that primary keys must have the explicit not null constraint. Or is there any way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged [logging](/questions/tagged/logging), so I assume you are interested in the PostgreSQL log file.

Unless you set `log_min_error_statement` to `fatal` or higher, the statement will always be included in the error message:

```
2020-04-02 14:40:28.253 CEST [3414] ERROR:  null value in column "a1" violates not-null constraint
2020-04-02 14:40:28.253 CEST [3414] DETAIL:  Failing row contains (12, null).
2020-04-02 14:40:28.253 CEST [3414] STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO a VALUES (12, NULL);
```

**Hint:** if you use `log_destination = csvlog`, the log file is easier to parse.

If you are interested in the message sent to the client, it depends on the client or API you are using to access PostgreSQL. The server sends the information along with the error message.

This is how it works with the `psql` client:

```
test=> \set VERBOSITY verbose
test=> INSERT INTO a VALUES (12, NULL);
ERROR:  23502: null value in column "a1" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (12, null).
SCHEMA NAME:  laurenz
TABLE NAME:  a
COLUMN NAME:  a1
LOCATION:  ExecConstraints, execMain.c:1960
```

Since you are interested in Python, here is a sample program that runs the same statement:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

from psycopg2 import connect, Error
from psycopg2.extensions import quote_ident

conn = connect("dbname=test user=laurenz")

cur = conn.cursor()

try:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO a VALUES (12, NULL)")
except Error as e:
    print("Error: {}".format(e.diag.message_primary))
    print("Detail: {}".format(e.diag.message_detail))
    print("SQLSTATE: {}".format(e.diag.sqlstate))
    print("Table: {}.{}".format(
               quote_ident(e.diag.schema_name, cur),
               quote_ident(e.diag.table_name, cur)
         ))

conn.commit()

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

The result is:

```
Error: null value in column "a1" violates not-null constraint
Detail: Failing row contains (12, null).
SQLSTATE: 23502
Table: "laurenz"."a"
```

Comment: I'm interested in what information will be accessible inside the application e.g. a Python program using psycopg2 in my case. I assume, that this is more or less the same information, that is accessible in the psql client. The verbosity setting could get me closer to what I need, not sure about the log files though. Thanks, and I will mark this as the accepted answer if I manage to work something out with your suggestions.

Comment: Is there any way to get this information (like TABLE NAME and COLUMN NAME with \set VERBOSITY verbose) in a stored function with something like "get stacked diagnostics"?

Comment: Ok, you forgot to include the relevant information that you are using psycopg2. `VERBOSITY` is only available in `psql`, but all the information displayed is *always* sent to the client. I'll see what I can find out about psycopg2.

Comment: I have added a Python sample.